# elastic search regex query for dollar ranges

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am attempting to create a regular expression query that will search content I have for dollar ranges.

That is items that follow the following format: $xxx,xxx.xx - $xxx,xxx.xx

Note that I want this to be somewhat lose. The only requirements are that the capture string must always start '$' with numbers after it (commas optional) and contain a '-' separating another group of numbers of the same format (starting with a $).

While I have found a regex that will satisfy this, and I believe I had adapted it to work with the elastic search syntax, I cannot seem to get any results back. I know that it should be finding results as well based on my knowledge of the dataset being queried.

Below is the query, if anyone could help me figure out what is wrong, or what I should be doing instead that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "_content": {
        "value": "$?<1-9>{1,}(,?<0-9>{1,3})+ *- *$?<1-9>{1,}(,?<0-9>{1,3})+",
        "flags": "INTERVAL"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried escaping your dollar signs, like: \$

Comment: You seem to misuse the INTERVAL syntax. Could you explain what the requirements are?

Comment: i-man, Elastic search does not use escape characters for dollar signs or dashes. Here is the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html 

Wiktor - I was using the interval syntax in order to find numbers that were between that range. Should I use characters instead? Even with the following I continue to find no results:
"$[1-9][0-9]*(,[0-9]{1,3})+ *- *$[1-9][0-9]*(,[0-9]{1,3})+".

Comment: I am attempting to search string contents of PDF documents (after saving the content as a string to elastic search) for instances of dollar ranges (Specifically $X-$X or $X - $X of some kind where X are comma separated numbers. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have a similar problem in the future:

My regular expression wasn't incorrect, rather I indexed items using the wrong tokenizer. The Standard tokenizer for elastic search stripped out $ and - and other special characters. After some customization I managed to get a reg ex that would return the expected results. Here is the final query I used:

```
GET pdfs3/pdf/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "_content": "($[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})+-$[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3}))"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Elasticsearch instance on hand, but the following should match your dollar ranges:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "_content": {
        "value": "\$[1-9][0-9]*((,|\.)[0-9]{1,3})+ *- *\$[1-9][0-9]*((,|\.)[0-9]{1,3})+"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Explanations

**Intervals** As Wiktor Stribiżew noted, you're misusing the interval option, which, AFAIK, doesn't take quantifiers. You could probably use an interval but here simple numeric ranges work too. `[1-9][0-9]` matches a number with at least 1 digit, not starting with a 0.

**Quantifiers** `{1,}` can be written `+`. Since I'm extracting the first range to match on *any digit but zero*, I should use `{0,}` or its equivalent: `*`.

**Dollar signs** As i-man noted, you need to escape the dollar signs. These are special signs that indicate the end of the string.

**Dot separator** Each group of 2-3 digits can be separated by either a comma or a dot. `(,|\.)` matches both.

Comment: I'm afraid that you might misunderstand what I was asking. While that would work for most traditional regular expression, Elastic Search has different regular expression syntax. Here is a link, they have a shorter reserved list, for example $ is not reserved. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html